# How to kickoff an asynchronous task in Ruby on Rails which would sequentially run a SQL, render a template and send an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class RefreshReportDataJob < ApplicationJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      user = User.find(id)       

      # 1. a) Run SQL1
      ApplicationRecord.connection.execute("<execute SQL1>")

      # 1. b) Run SQL2
      ApplicationRecord.connection.execute("<execute SQL2>")

      # 2. render erb template
        excel_report = ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
        :template => 'forecast/show_xlsx'
      )

      # 3. Upload Excel generated in step 2 to AWS bucket
        s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2') 
        my_bucket = s3.bucket('my-bucket')
        my_bucket.create
        name = File.basename 'MyExcel'
        obj = s3.bucket('my-bucket').object(name) 
        obj.upload_file('MyExcel')

      # 4. Send an email to the user stating the Excel is available in the AWS bucket
        sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
        recipient = 'receiver@gmail.com'
        subject = 'Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for Ruby)'

        # The HTML body of the email. 
        htmlbody =  '<h1>Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for Ruby)</h1>'\
          '<p>This email was sent with <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses/">'\
            'Amazon SES</a> using the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/">'\
            'AWS SDK for Ruby</a>.'
        # The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients. 
        textbody = 'This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for Ruby.'
        # Specify the text encoding scheme. 
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
        # Create a new SES client in the us-west-2 region. # Replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES. 
        ses = Aws::SES::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2')
        # Try to send the email. 
        begin  
          # Provide the contents of the email.  
            ses.send_email(
              destination: {
                to_addresses: [
                  recipient
                ]
              },
               message: {
                body: {
                  html: {
                    charset: encoding,
                    data: htmlbody
                  },
                  text: {
                    charset: encoding,
                    data: textbody
                  }
              },
              subject: {
                    charset: encoding,
                    data: subject
                  }
              },
              source: sender
            )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a few questions here:

1. Will SQL 1. a) and 1. b) run sequentially?
2. Currently SQL seems to run fine but nothing from step 2 seem to work
3. Can I render an erb template from within an ActiveJob function?
4. Can I upload files to AWS bucket from within an ActiveJob function?
5. Can I send an email using AWS SES account (using AWS SDK) from within an ActiveJob function?
6. I also get an error now stating that my template was not found; am not sure why I get this error:

```
    ActionView::MissingTemplate Missing template my_controller/my_template with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :axlsx]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/Mailer/cfps_app/app/views"
```

My template is present inside `app/views/my_controller` and the error above says `searched in app/views` - is that a problem? - does this mean Rails searched inside all subfolders in `app/views`?

7. Also, my template generates an `.xlsx` file.

   a. Can `render_string` return only a string? or can it return an excel as well?

   b. How do upload the Excel returned in the above step into the AWS bucket?

Please help!

Comment: I'd really advise to learn RoR best-practices first before considering background tasks. This code is in need of some serious refactoring. Store the attachment via an ActiveStorage object for instance, and the render the e-mail with ActiveMailer.

Comment: To answer your questions, re 1: they should run sequentially, but if you want to be sure, wrap them in a Transaction. 2/ what did you do to debug? 3/ Yes you can, but should you? 4/ sure, 5/ sure, but you should use ActiveMailer, 6/ did you follow the path to see that it is indeed there? 7/ does it really render an XLSX file, what gem do you use for that?

Comment: @bo-oz - Thanks much for the reply! 3) I need to render an erb template (which renders an Excel) AFTER the queries in step 1 complete. The entire SQL execution and Excel rendering takes more than 5 minutes because of which I need to do both in an ActiveJob operation so that the user does not get timed out. Hope this is a good reason. 7) I am using `axlsx` gem and it definitely renders an excel

Comment: 1) 4) Understood. Thanks! 6) Yes I checked the path and the template is very much present in `app/views/my_controller` path

Comment: 5) Understood; but my application is hosted on AWS cloud and I need to send emails through Amazon Simple Email Service account (using Amazon SDK which is provided in `aws-sdk-rails` gem. The documentation on how to use the SDk to send emails is provided in page 122 of this PDF - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/aws-sdk-ruby-dg.pdf  I need to send this email right after the excel template rendering is done - hence I need this also to be done in ActiveJob

Comment: 2) Usually a message like this - `Rendered /my_controller/my_template.xlsx.axlsx (4.1 ms)` - is displayed when a template is rendered - I don't see that message for my template in the Rails console. Also I explicitly got a `template missing` error for my template which I had posted in item# 6) in my original question. This is what I had done to debug. Please advise!

Comment: I believe if the missing template issue is fixed, that would help with a bunch of issues. Not sure why I am getting this error though. Please help!

Comment: FYI - I had posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56114110/applicationcontroller-renderer-render-is-unable-to-locate-partials-in-ruby-on-ra?noredirect=1#comment98862399_56114110 for issue# 6 and this is resolved now!

Comment: Since `#6` is resolved an my templates are being rendered as per the rails console messages (I am getting the message `Rendering my_controller/my_template` now in the console and I don't get the `Missing template` error anymore), the answer to #3 is a definite Yes!

Comment: so issues `#4, 5 & 7` are pending now. Thanks!

Comment: You can set S3 and SES as engines when configuring Rails ActiveStorage & ActiveMailer respectively. Look into the documentation of both modules to find out more. Is pretty easy... so bascially you don't want to be referencing S3 or SES directly, but use the intended modules for this within Rails.

Comment: sending mail through SES: https://www.sitepoint.com/deliver-the-mail-with-amazon-ses-and-rails/

Comment: ActiveStorage with S3: https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/setting-up-rails-5-active-storage-with-amazon-s3-3d158cf021ff

Comment: @bo-oz - Thank you very much for the pointers! I thought AWS SDK works completely outside the ActiveMailer - I was not aware that AWS adapters are available for ActiveMailer (similar to SuckerPunch adapter for ActiveJob). 

I had a glance at the documentation you pointed out just now. Looks like I have quite some work to do - and am also working on soerting out seom AWS access issues as well.

So I guess it would take a couple of days for me to complete the implementation using ActiveStorage and ActiveMailer as you suggested. So please bear with me for a couple of days until I reply back!

Comment: @bo-oz Until then you could probably post this as the answer to this question and I will accept it once I complete my implementation. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, I'll write a complete answer.

Comment: That'd be great. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: sure, no problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your Qs:

1. Will SQL 1. a) and 1. b) run sequentially?
   **Yes, but you could wrap it in a Transaction just to be sure**
2. Currently SQL seems to run fine but nothing from step 2 seem to work
   **Please share what you did to debug**
3. Can I render an erb template from within an ActiveJob function?
   **yes**
4. Can I upload files to AWS bucket from within an ActiveJob function?
   **yes, but use ActiveStorage as Abstraction layer: https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/setting-up-rails-5-active-storage-with-amazon-s3-3d158cf021ff .**
5. Can I send an email using AWS SES account (using AWS SDK) from within an ActiveJob function?
   **yes, but use ActiveMailer as an Abstraction layer: https://www.sitepoint.com/deliver-the-mail-with-amazon-ses-and-rails/ .**
6. I also get an error now stating that my template was not found; am not sure why I get this error:

   ```
   ActionView::MissingTemplate Missing template my_controller/my_template with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :axlsx]}. Searched in:
   * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/Mailer/cfps_app/app/views"
   ```

My template is present inside app/views/my_controller and the error above says searched in app/views - is that a problem? - does this mean Rails searched inside all subfolders in app/views?
**You already fixed this by checking file exists right?**

7. Also, my template generates an .xlsx file.

a. Can render_string return only a string? or can it return an excel as well?
**Well techinically Excel is also a string, but it has certain headers set that make it an XLSX, you are able to mimic this in Ruby. I guess your Excel gem already takes care of this.**

b. How do upload the Excel returned in the above step into the AWS bucket?
**Just write the string to file and copy that over to S3 using ActiveStorage**

Comment: Thanks for the answer again - just 1 question though please? In the AWS SDK for Rails documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/aws-sdk-ruby-dg.pdf - this is the sample code shown to upload files to AWS bucket - `require 'aws-sdk-s3'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'      s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
file = 'C:\file.txt' bucket = 'my-bucket'      # Get just the file name name = File.basename(file)
# Create the object to upload obj = s3.bucket(bucket).object(name)
# Upload it      obj.upload_file(file) `

And this does not use ActiveStorage

Comment: But the above code does not work for me - what am I missing here? I would really like to understand the discrepancy here - just our of sheer curiosity please...

Comment: You should not use that approach in Rails... use ActiveStorage instead, read my earlier link. You just configure the S3 bucket and the credentials, and let Rails deal with the rest!