# ApplicationController.renderer.render is unable to locate partials in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to render an Excel template after a SQL query completes. And the SQL takes 3-4 minutes to complete. So I am implementing both the SQL execution and excel template rendering inside an `ActiveJob`.

I am calling my template `my_template` like this:

```
class RefreshReportDataJob < ApplicationJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    # <- Run a SQL first here ->

    # After SQL above is complete, render an Excel template
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(
    :file => 'my_controller/my_template', :formats => [:xlsx, :html]
    )
  end
```

This template is present inside `views/my_controller/`. This template renders 3 partials `_my_partial1, _my_partial2, _my_partial3` - all of them are also present inside the same folder as `my_template` -> `views/my_controller`.

While rendering `my_template`, I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error Missing partial application/_my_partial1.xlsx.axlsx with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xlsx, :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder, :axlsx]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rails/Mailer/my_app/app/views"
```

If Rails is able to locate `my_template`, why is it not able to locate the partial `my_partial1` which is also present in the same folder? Please help!

Comment: Are the file extensions the same across all of the partials?

Comment: Yes. All of them have the same extension - `.xlsx.axlsx`. In fact all these partials were rendered perfectly fine when I was rendering them from within the controller. This issue appears only after I moved the rendering inside an `ActiveJob`

Comment: Also, why is Rails looking for the partial inside `application/` folder? Where does that folder exist?

Comment: Not sure. It's a shot in the dark, but maybe it's queueing off of your controller name since you're calling `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Should I call `MyController.renderer.render` instead?

Comment: Yeah, give that a shot

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you very much!!! Would you want to drop that as an answer here?

Comment: Great, sure, I'll add the answer

Comment: That was brilliant! Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: Glad it worked. I guess this is one of those cases where Rails can sometimes be a little too magical. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `ApplicationController.render`. This will cause Rails to look for the template at `application/_your_partial`.

You'll have to change the call to `render` to point to the corresponding controller/view template.

So if your template is in `app/views/my_controller/_my_partial`, you need to call `MyController.renderer.render(...)`.

Comment: @NM_Pennypacker @bo-oz - Looks like `ApplicationController::renderer` does not have a `render_to_string` method. If I would like to store the output of the render in a string, what should I do here? Please advise? Is there an alternative to `render_to_string` here that I could use?

Comment: The `render_to_string` method is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb, so you'll have to import that functionality. Perhaps `'include ActionController::Rendering'`, and then calling `ActionController::Rendering.render_to_string()`. If that doesn't work I'd ask it as a new question